# Inserting custom names for the Bundeled Product Options

Tags: magento

How can I insert custom names for my bundled product options in the admin area?

Here is an image of what I mean.

[image]

I want to be able able to insert custom names for these product options. 
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: if I remember correctly, isn't that in **Attributes**?

Comment: Can you tell where to find more info about what you mean?

Comment: or can you please elaborate a bit your answer? @balexandre

Comment: it's not an answer, it's a comment ;) I'm installing Magento in Amazon  (one click install from [Bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/magento/cloud))  and I will tell you exactly what to do in an answer :)

Comment: Thank you, then i will wait for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup a Cloud Account ([from Bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/magento/cloud) and available for about an hour) and it's pretty straight forward:

```
Catalog > Attributes
```

all you need is to create and set those there, as the Colors in your image are called **Attributes**

you can always see how [Magento Demo Store](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/) is [setting them up](http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product_attribute/index/key/4fb24ee0ab3a13fc63295d00e0bcdb09/) or as I said above, just navigate to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` or `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes Sets`

You should see a demo or buy a book about Magento (their manual helps a lot) if you don't know what are this really standard piece of a product customization.

Comment: I am confident that i have a basic understanding of how attributes work as i have been using them for some time now. But I still struggle  to understand how to change the product option name through an attribute. You see, my bundled items are simple products and at the moment it is shown their name (Black, White, Red, etc) but on this specific bundled product, i want them to be (Black Standard, White Standard, Red Standard, etc) If i create a new attribute and put value for them, then it doesn't change anything in the name of these options.

Comment: when you create your bundle, the first thing that the "Add Product" asks is what is the "attribute set", you can create your own just for a group of products and add/remove what "attributes" does that have. - n your example, you should see what "attribute set" does that Bundle product have and edit each individual attributes. Careful not to mess up with existing products that share the same attributes